# Syntax error in Windows resource (.rc) file

Tags: windows, syntax-error, resource-files, rc

I have a problem with a package of files, including a main.rc. I never worked with rc files, but I have to resolve a problem for a friend of mine. This is my "main.rc":

```
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef GCC_WINDRES
  VS_VERSION_INFO       VERSIONINFO
#else
  VS_VERSION_INFO       VERSIONINFO MOVEABLE IMPURE LOADONCALL DISCARDABLE
#endif

FILEVERSION     1,1,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION  1,1,0,0
FILEFLAGSMASK       VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK

#ifdef _DEBUG
  FILEFLAGS     1
#else
  FILEFLAGS     0
#endif

FILEOS      VOS_DOS_WINDOWS32
FILETYPE        VFT_DLL
FILESUBTYPE     0   // not used

BEGIN
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    BLOCK "040904E4"
    //language ID = U.S. English, char set = Windows, Multilingual
    BEGIN
      VALUE "FileDescription",  "myProtectoR\0"
      VALUE "FileVersion",  "1.1.0.0\0"
      VALUE "InternalName", "myprotector.exe\0"
      VALUE "LegalCopyright",   "(C) 2010-2011 Roberto Rossi\0"
      VALUE "OriginalFilename", "myprotector.exe\0"
      VALUE "ProductName",  "myProtectoR\0"
      VALUE "ProductVersion",   "1.1.0.0\0"
      VALUE "Comments","myProtectoR by Roberto Rossi (http://www.redchar.net)\0"
    END
  END
  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0409, 1252
  END
END
```

I get a "syntax error" (not so specific uh?) at line 6, but I don't know why. Can anyone help my with that?

Comment: Can you post the exact error!?

Comment: "I get a syntax error" sounds misleading.  Surely it is your "friend" that gets the error?  You must document the toolchain he is using.  Occam's razor says he forgot to define GCC_WINDRES.  Just get rid of it completely, those attributes stopping being meaningful 20 years ago.

Comment: @Robert this is the error itself. <img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img907/223/11fF6V.png">. The 28 is the line number, then there is the path in which those files are saved; the message is "syntax error", nothing else.

Comment: @Hans He doesn't know anything about C++ and asked me to modify this file. Anyway, I tried to compile it before doing anything, this is the original code. I tried to do him a favour controlling this code, I didn't expect to work with something I never saw, even because it's something deprecated. Therefore my help request.